# Several Buttons using the same UIActionSheetDelegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view that contains 5 buttons.  When each button is tapped the UIActionSheetDelegate method is called: -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

I have each buttons tag property set 0-4.  I'm having a hard time with the delegate method finding out which button.tag was sent.  Is the sender.tag information passed along to the action sheets delegate methods?

For the delegate method I use a case statement to find out which button was pressed on the action sheet and I guess I'll use an if statement to determine which sender.tag == 0 etc.  I'm just a little confused at this point and need a little assistance if at all possible.

As always thanks in advance!

T

Answer (score 1):

You use the `buttonIndex` that is passed to `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` to determine which button was pressed.  The buttons are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I have a case statement to handle the button indexes in delegate method but I need the sender.tag (from UIButton) to know which case statement to execute and in this case the delegate protocol will need to know which button (not the button from the action sheet)was pressed.  I have 5 UIButtons each of which has ActionSheet.  So the delegate method needs to know which UIButton was pressed.  I hope I explained that clear enough.  thanks

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem.  So you have 5 `UIButtons` and tapping each one of those brings up the same action sheet.  When you tap a button on the action sheet you want to know a) which button on the action sheet was pressed and b) which `UIButton` initiated the action sheet.  Is that correct, or am I still confused?